# Writing updates to OLAP cube

Tags: olap, adomd.net

What is the easiest way to write user entered measure values (sales forcast) to the SQL Server Analysis Services OLAP cube from a .Net client application?

I'm aware that underlying fact table can be updated with DML statements and that cube can be reprocessed but I'm looking for alternatives.

Regards,
Aleksandar

Answer (score 1):

We use pivot table Ranet OLAP for editing  cube data.
View sample Simple PivotTable Widget - PivotTaple with Updateable 
[Writing updates to OLAP cube](https://bi.galaktikasoft.com/sl/ranetolap/).

Comment: We have a new control on the Silverlight for data entry. The table can be customized by the user, you can add / delete rows and columns, rename, customize styles (gradient, etc.), quick filter, implemented a quick search. To cells can add comments.

Comment: Editing data in the Pivot Grid: 1) Setting up the Writeback partition for the database Adventure Works; 2) Setting up the MDX query and the UPDATE SCRIPT; 3) Editing data in the Pivot Grid. Go to https://ranetuilibraryolap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Editing%20data%20in%20the%20pivot%20grid&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 0):

I nearly got into a project like this once. It did not go ahead, which I was very grateful for, after looking into the work involved. My advice to you is to run away!!!

You do not have to update actual cube data, or reprocess though - depending on how complex your user-entered data is going to be. I believe this is covered in Microsoft's standard MDX course, the notes of which you may be able to find online (sorry, I've since disposed of my copy). This depends on whether you want to learn MDX though, which is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ADOMD .Net to do Writeback. You can ADOMDCommand to wrap UPDATE CUBE Statements.

**ADOMD .Net**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123483(v=SQL.100).aspx

Link below talks about some of the issues in this approach, if you are doing too many updates together.

http://www.developmentnow.com/g/112_2006_1_0_0_677198/writeback-in-ADOMD-NET.htm